# C++ vscode, When I can Input in Terminal, it Automatically Prints the Thread Instance

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Recently getting into c++ from python and using vscode with MinGW.

I can build my script just fine, but when I run it, it shows this:

[image: Debug Console Output]

I want it so that I can type what's going in, not just some random stuff. An explanation of why this is happening would be appreciated too!

##### Simple_Countdown.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int int_0;
    cout << "Input a number to countdown: ";
    cin >> int_0;
    cout << int_0 << endl;
    while(int_0 > 0)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        int_0--;
        cout << int_0 << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the 'Terminal' tab if you're just running the code.